# CSS3 List Menu Fading Transition Not Working

Tags: list, css, menu, fade

I have an unordered list navigation menu in which I'm using css3 to fade in the background image on hover. The swapping of the images is working, but there is no transition or fade. Instead its just immediate. You can see here http://bokushucom.ipage.com/Miltonkarate/karate_test/

this is the mark up I'm using

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="navMenu">
                <div class="table">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lil' Dragons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Junior Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Adult Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kendo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tai Chi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
                 </div>    
            </div><!--end of navMenu-->
</div><!--end of header-->
```

and the CSS

```
#navMenu {
    position:absolute;
    height:34px;
    width:940px;
    bottom:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    left:0;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style:none;
}

.table {
    display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navMenu li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
    border-left:1px solid #5A5A5A;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
    position:relative;
    line-height: 34px;
    }

#navMenu li a {
    display:block;
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    background:url(../images/navMenuBG.jpg) repeat-x;
    -webkit-transition: background 2s 3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background 2s 3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background 2s 3s ease-in;
    transition: background 2s 3s ease-in;
    }

#navMenu a:hover {
    background:url(../images/navMenu_shadow.png);
    height:35px;
    color: #666;
    }
```

I'm pretty new to CSS3. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: u are changing images. i am not sure how transition works with images!! better use backh=ground color and apply transition on it

Answer (score 1):

There are a **few things** you need to **correct on your code**,

- Change   `#navMenu a:hover` to `#navMenu li a:hover`. This is just to make it more specific.
- You are specifying duration **two times** on your **transition** line. Change `transition: background 2s 3s ease-in;` to `transition: background 2s ease-in;`. And consequently change all the transition lines.

Here's a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2BJa/).

I hope this resolved your issue.

> ***Just to note:*** 2s or 3s in the transition makes the effect look very slow. Make it less and it'll definitely look better.

Comment: I'd recommend using around a .2s transition. John is right in saying your duration is too long right now